# Asp net core api post request with many to many controller

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core, asp.net-web-api, entity-framework-core

I have simple question. I have 2 models, coctails and ingredients:

```
    public class Coctails
{
    [Required]
    public long CoctailsId { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string CookingMethod { get; set; }

    public double Price { get; set; }

    public List<Ingredients> CoctailIngredients { get; set; }
}

    public class Ingredients
{

    [Required]
    public long IngredientsId { get; set; }

    
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public double Amount { get; set; }

    public double Price { get; set; }

    public List<Coctails> CoctailsWithThisIngredient { get; set; }
}
```

I am saving 1 ingredient using postman with following request:

```
{
"Name":"vodka",
"Amount":1000,
"Price":100}
```

After that I am trying to add new coctail with post request:

```
{
"Name":"vodka s pivom" ,
"CookingMethod":"rubilovo",
"Price":100,
"coctailIngredients":
[
    {
        "Name" : "vodka",
        "Amount" : 50
    }
]}
```

And I have error with endless loop (but I need those 2 fields CoctailIngredients  and CoctailsWithThisIngredient to tell ef that this is many to many relations and it is making 3rd connection table for me)...so how to avoid such situation?

My db context class:

```
    public class DatabaseContext : DbContext
{
    public DatabaseContext()
    {
    }

    public DbSet<Coctails> Coctails { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Ingredients> Ingredients { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Coctails>()
                .HasMany(c => c.CoctailIngredients)
                .WithMany(s => s.CoctailsWithThisIngredient)
                .UsingEntity(j => j.ToTable("CoctailsWithIngredients"));
    }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlite("Filename=BarDb.db");
    }


}
```

My POST method:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<ActionResult<Coctails>> PostCoctails(Coctails coctails)
    {
        _context.Coctails.Attach(coctails);

        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

        return CreatedAtAction("GetCoctails", new { id = coctails.CoctailsId }, coctails);
    }
```

Comment: And your post mthod looks like?

Comment: Added it to question

Answer (score 3):

The only way to keep many-to-many relations is to add the third table. If you use Ef core 5+, ef can create this table for you in shadow, but it is always better to create it explicitly:

```
public class CoctailIngridient
{
     [Key]
    public long Id { get; set; }

    public long CoctailId { get; set; }
    public long IngredientId { get; set; }
    public virtual Coctail Coctail { get; set; }
    public virtual Ingredient Ingridient { get; set; }
 }

public class Coctail
{
    [Key]
    public long CoctailsId { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string CookingMethod { get; set; }

    public double Price { get; set; }

    public List<CoctailIngredient> CoctailIngredients { get; set; }

    //only for ef core 5+
    public List<Ingredient> Ingredients { get; set; }
 }

 public class Ingredient
{

    [Key]
    public long IngredientId { get; set; }

    
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public double Amount { get; set; }

    public double Price { get; set; }

     public List<CoctailIngredient> CoctailIngredients { get; set; }

     //only for ef core 5+
    public List<Coctail> Coctails { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Adding third table manually wasn't helped. Error still reproduces and new record in Ingredients table appears :(

Comment: Should I add this 3rd table in db context? And Can you show OnModelCreating method?

Answer (score 1):

Adding third model class and removing OnModelCreating method from Database context method did the trick. I guess problem is solved. Thanks for help!

And one more really important thing, I've also have added 'NotMapped' tag above my

```
public List<Coctails> CoctailsWithThisIngredient { get; set; }
```

and

```
public List<Ingredients> CoctailIngredients { get; set; }
```

Comment: You will need to have explicit third table to store the amount of the ingredient needed for the coctail. At least if you don't want to have a lot of ingrdients with the same name in database.

Comment: This doesn't make much sense. If you don't map the properties nothing will ever populate them. Did you read the EF documentation on many-to-many associations?

Comment: Of course I did and I have absolutely no idea how....but it works!! I haven't did anything but all I've described above